# Windows Explorer: Context menu to a especific folder (background)

Tags: windows, windows-registry, context-menu

*(This is not a duplicate - I have checked before asking)*

Both .reg commands add a custom item entry to a folder context menu:

**1. Context menu to folders:**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\my custom command]
@="My command name"
"AppliesTo"="C:\\My specific Folder\\"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\my custom command\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""
```

**2. Context menu to folder background (empty area of a folder):**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\my custom command]
@="My command name"
"AppliesTo"="C:\\My specific Folder\\"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\my custom command\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""
```

The line `"AppliesTo"="C:\\My specific Folder\\"` set which specific folder the menu entry will appear.

The problem is in **(2)** it won't accept `"AppliesTo"="C:\\My specific Folder\\"`. If I put that registry value (`"AppliesTo"`) the menu entry won't appear at all.
How do I set a specific folder to **(2)**?

Comment: I'm finding the same behaviour, and have not found out how to use an AppliesTo alongside Directory\Background.

Comment: See this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144171(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to use property names like:

```
AppliesTo = System.ItemName:"foo"
System.FileName
System.ItemFolderPathDisplay
System.ItemPathDisplay
```

There's a lot of these. Check out: https://freeswitch.org/stash/projects/FS/repos/freeswitch/browse/libs/portaudio/src/hostapi/wasapi/mingw-include/propkey.h?at=FS-3387_new_pa

Comment: I have tried all these. Please, post a working example. Say, "C:\My folder"